# Email Submission not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with a Newsletter subscription popup, it has Email address and Submit button. The intention is
1. When new customer enter his/her email id and click SUBMIT button, two actions need to happen.

1. The email has be sent to current database and
2. Redirect customer to thank you page.

I have the thank you page webpage. I have the database information. But this in a ecommerce website, I have limited access. I already have similar subscription in one of the webpage, I am trying to replicate that as popup.  I am attaching the codes that I have.

My HTML body tag:

```
         <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="28">
        <br>
          <onclick="javascript:location.href='https://www.thankyou.html'">
           <input type="submit"  value="SUBMIT" width="260px">
   </form>
```

Code from my existing webpage for database:

When I click SUBMIT, it redirects me to https://www.mywebsite.com/v/Config_FullStoreURLMailingList_subscribe.asp

Instead it should be redirecting customer to "Thankyou.html"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have confused with onclick event. Try using it like this,

```
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="28">
        <br>
           <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:location.href='https://www.mysite.com/thankyou.html'" value="SUBMIT" width="260px">
   </form>
```